# Meta StackOverflow questions are now limited to one per page

Tags: bug, meta

Probably related to the issue of no questions showing up on the popular tag, I'm now stuck with seeing only one question per page on Meta, no matter which "question list" view I choose. Even http://meta.stackoverflow.com gives me one question per page:

[image]

Stack Overflow itself is not affected for me.

EDIT:

After posting this question, the frontpage list of questions updated to show mine in addition to the one that was already visible. So now I have *two* questions on the page... progress! However, if I refresh the page, it goes back to only showing one question.

Comment: related: [How does SE remember my preferences without a POST but just a GET?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298600/839601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably clicked on a link or something that changed your page size to 1. To fix it, you can simply click on the 15, 30, or 50 at the bottom right of the list (next to "per page"). The fact that one of them isn't highlighted suggests that you aren't using a default value.

Comment: Hmm that must be what happened; all the pages have the `pagesize=1` bit in their URL. Odd.

Comment: Hm, this wouldn't have anything to do with [Jeremy Banks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/298783/revisions), would it? @TylerH

Comment: @1999 Actually that probably is what happened. I do remember visiting that page earlier... I must have clicked on that image.

Comment: @TylerH: You don't have to click on it actually. The browser sends a request to the server to request for the image, so the page number setting is changed.